# Assigning a unique id to group of records based on lookup values in multiple vars in sas

Tags: sas, grouping

I have a dataset in the below view and would like to assign a unique id to the a set of records based on data availability and match at different variables.

```
"Policy No" "Previous Policy No"    "Next policy No"
101 55  110
110 101 201
220 110 
511     532
532 511
```

Expected dataset:

```
"Customer Id"   "Policy No" "Previous Policy No"    "Next policy No"
1   101 55  110
1   110 101 201
1   220 110 
2   511     532
2   532 511
```

Comment: A bit confusing. Could you please show what you have tried and simulate desirable outcome? Please use Ctl+K to format code and separate columns names with either commas or put them in quotes.

Comment: I believe this is usually known as chained look up problem. Here's one solution, but yours is slightly more complicated I think, http://support.sas.com/kb/25/029.html

Comment: @Reeza.. thats the solution i was looking at.. thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your question, but you can generate a unique ID by using MD5 and give it the variables that form your key.

For example:

```
data want; 
ID = PUT(MD5(CATS("Var1","Var2")),$HEX32.);
PUT ID; 
RUN;
```

Result: 5BC449EDA5CF2BA878ABE53CB3955D38

This ID is going to be unique. You just need to decide on your business keys and feed them into MD5. Do some data cleansing, so for example upcase all your variables if your keys differ in case, but not in meaning.